# Design pattern used in logging framework

Tags: logging, singleton, factory

I tried to search this question on internet, however couldn't find the answer.
Please excuse and point me if the question is duplicate.

Many times, I have been told that Logger uses Singleton as well as Factory pattern (i.e. when we are passing different debug level - ERROR, DEBUG... etc then getLogger() will return different objects)

I need more explanation, how Singleton and Factory pattern both are internally implemented with logger.

Please help.

/Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ambient Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx). In different context via ambient context you can set logging in database, event log, etc. Also via ambient context you can control log level functionality.